# O que tem de errado no meu code?

Tags: c

Eu quero fazer um jogo de forca simples com algumas palavras pré determinadas,to bem no início ainda...acontece que tá dando erro assim ó

```
escolhendo palavra...
SIGSEGV on thread : 1685113120"
```

Meu código é esse

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b=0;
    char q;
    char chamar(int z);
    printf("escolhendo palavra...\n");
    srand(time NULL);
    a=(rand()%4);
    q = chamar(a);
    b=strlen(q);
    printf("%d",b);
    for(int x=0;x<=b;x++)
    {
        printf("_");
        }
}

char chamar (int z)
{
    switch(z)
    {
        case 0:
        return "soda";
        break;
        case 1:
        return "hair";
        break;
        case 2:
        return "paper";
        break;
        case 3:
        return "telephone";
        break;
        case 4:
        return "sky";
        break;
        default:
        return "errinho";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem várias coisas erradas mesmo, mas comecemos pelas que fazem o seu programa funcionar.

- A sua função `chamar` pretende devolver uma string, então tem de devolver algo do tipo `char*` e não `char`, pois `char` é apenas uma letra. Essa correção tem de ser feita em todos os locais que usam a função
- No `for(int x=0;x<=b;x++)` tem na comparação `<=` quando devia ter apenas `<`
- Se faz `return` dentro de cada `case` no `switch` então não precisa de ter `break`

Código após correções indicadas:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

char *chamar(int z); //com *

int main() {
    int a,b=0;
    char *q; //com *
    printf("escolhendo palavra...\n");
    srand(time(NULL));
    a=(rand()%4);
    q = chamar(a);
    b=strlen(q);
    printf("%d",b);
    for(int x=0; x<b /*< em vez de <=*/; x++) {
        printf("_");
    }
}

char* /*com * */ chamar (int z) {
    switch(z) {
    case 0: return "soda";
    case 1: return "hair";
    case 2: return "paper";
    case 3: return "telephone";
    case 4: return "sky";
    default: return "errinho";
    }
}
```

[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/h65fFN)

Comment: C permite declarar `i` dentro do `for`? Não precisa declarar no início da função?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Depende das flags de compilação. Se estiver a ser compilado em C89 por exemplo é exatamente dessa maneira e não permite, mas em versões mais modernas já permite.

Comment: Muito obrigado, obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Apenas para complementar: Assim como o @Isac disse, essa sintaxe não funciona no C89 porque é padrão do C99. O `i`, geralmente, é uma abreviação de "index" ("índice"). Declarar fora do `for` é considerado uma boa prática da programação por ser uma sintaxe exigido na perspectiva de um algoritmo. Isto quer dizer que, caso precise acessar o último valor do índice, apenas será possível se o `i` estiver declarado fora do escopo do `for` porque toda a varíavel local habita dentro de uma função, portanto, quando uma função termina, tudo que é declarado dentro do escopo de `for` é destruído.

Comment: Lembrando que "declaração" e "definição" são coisas diferentes.